# Keep an <input> and a <p> on the same line

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on a text editor and I have come across a problem: no matter what I do, this input and this p element will not stay on the same line (but only when the p has content). My code is below. I have tried `display: inline-block;` in my css, but this did not work. Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).keyup(function () {
                    var a = $("#typ").val();
                    var b = $("#txt").text();
                    if (a == "") {
                        //if backspace
                        var c = b.substring(0, b.length - 1);
                    } else {
                        //otherwise
                        var a = a.substring(1, a.length);
                        var c = b.concat(a);
                    }
                    $("#txt").text(c);
                    $("#typ").val(" ");
                });
            });
```

```css
.type:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
            <p class="text" id="txt"></p>
            <input class="type" id="typ" type="text" value=" "/>
</div>
```

EDIT: I made the input more visible!

Comment: Looks like your snippet above is not working. Please update your question

Comment: Would using a `span` work for you? If not - just use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` on your `p` tag. https://jsfiddle.net/64rnegyL/

Comment: @RohithKP I think it does work, it's just the the `p` and the `input` have no content, and therefore don't show.

Comment: @RohithKP It does work, but I had made the input nearly invisible. Sorry!

Comment: I think it is better to use `label` instead of `p`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `p` display to `inline` or `inline-block`. By default, it is a block element, so it will break a line.

Answer (score 2):

The one being a block element is the `p`, so you can use `display: inline`. This will convert a block element, without elements before or after, to an inline element, like a text character. You can also use `display: inline-block` which will convert it to a block that can be inlined.

```css
.type {
    border: none;
}
.type:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
.text {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
            <p class="text" id="txt">I have a p.</p>
            <input class="type" id="typ" type="text" value="I have an input."/>
            Huh! Not going to make the joke...
</div>
```